# Linear regression(Python)-getting different results for different algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I implemented gradient descent for linear regression in Python for a data read from csv file. below is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as op
from sklearn import preprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style

def CostFunc(theta,x,y):
    m,n = x.shape; 
    theta = theta.reshape((n,1));
    #y = y.reshape((m,1));
    #x=x.reshape((m,1))
    J = 0.5*sum(np.square((X.dot(theta)-y)))[0]/m;
    return J;


def gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters):
    m,n = X.shape;
    initial_iter = num_iters
    J = np.zeros((num_iters,1));
    while num_iters > 0:
        theta = theta - (alpha*np.sum(((X.dot(theta)-y)*X),axis=0)/m).reshape((n,1))
        J[initial_iter-num_iters][0]=CostFunc(theta,X,y)
        num_iters=num_iters-1

    return theta,J;


data = np.loadtxt(open("ex1data2.txt","rb"),delimiter=",",skiprows=1)
nr,nc = data.shape
X=data[:,0:nc - 1]
X=preprocessing.scale(X)
X=np.insert(X,0,1,axis=1)
y= data[:,[nc - 1]]
m , n = X.shape;
#initial_theta = np.zeros(len(n));
initial_theta = np.zeros((n,1));
theta,J=gradientDescent(X,y,initial_theta,0.01,400)
J=J.reshape(400)
count=0
grp=np.zeros((400,2));
for value in J:

    grp[count][0] = count+1
    grp[count][1] = value
    count = count+1



plt.plot(grp)
plt.legend(loc=4)
plt.xlabel('iter')
plt.ylabel('cost')
plt.show()



print(theta)
```

## optimal_theta = Result.x;

I ran 400 iterations and got a decreasing plot of cost as follows[iteration vs cost plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dydDy.png)

Then I used one of the custom algorithms on the same data with the following code

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as op
from sklearn import preprocessing

def Sigmoid(z):
    return 1/(1 + np.exp(-z));

def Gradient(theta,x,y):
    m , n = x.shape
    theta = theta.reshape((n,1));
    #y = y.reshape((m,1))
    #x=x.reshape((m,1))
    #sigmoid_x_theta = Sigmoid(x.dot(theta));
    grad = (np.sum(((X.dot(theta)-y)*X),axis=0)/m);
    return grad.flatten();

def CostFunc(theta,x,y):
    m,n = x.shape; 
    theta = theta.reshape((n,1));
    #y = y.reshape((m,1));
    #x=x.reshape((m,1))
    J = 0.5*sum(np.square((X.dot(theta)-y)))[0]/m;
    return J;


data = np.loadtxt(open("ex1data2.txt","rb"),delimiter=",",skiprows=1)
nr,nc = data.shape
X=data[:,0:nc - 1]
X=preprocessing.scale(X)
X=np.insert(X,0,1,axis=1)
y= data[:,[nc - 1]]
m , n = X.shape;
#initial_theta = np.zeros(len(n));
initial_theta = np.zeros((n,1));

Result = op.minimize(fun = CostFunc, 
                                x0 = initial_theta, 
                               args = (X, y),
                               method = 'TNC',
                               jac = Gradient);






print("====================")       
print(Result)        
#optimal_theta = Result.x;
```

The theta values of the first case were
[[ 333032.07465084] [ 100130.7408761 ] [   3699.66611303]]

While from the second I get the following output
    fun: 2066502781.7118049
     jac: array([ -6.45345806e-11,   7.84261236e-10,  -2.42370452e-10])
 message: 'Local minimum reached (|pg| ~= 0)'
    nfev: 27
     nit: 13
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([ 339119.45652174,  110248.92165868,   -6226.22670554])

I am assuming x: array([ 339119.45652174,  110248.92165868,   -6226.22670554]) to be the theta value.

Why am I getting the values different for 2 cases?

Comment: Potentially you are running into local optima. Try initialising theta with values of the same order of magnitude of these two solutions (*not* zeros), repeat 1000 times, plot the two distribution of solutions in both cases (3 distributions each). That will tell you if these two solutions are actually significantly different.

Comment: I might be wrong here, but was having the impression that linear regression cost function does not have local optima and can only have global optima.

Comment: That is only true for linear regression with a single variable. But you have multiple predictors, in which case the answer is no. Trivially, if two of your predictors are exactly the same (or more generally, are collinear), then you have an infinite number of solutions that have the same cost.

Comment: For example, you want to explain y and you have the predictors a, b, and c. Let a and b be identical (to make things easier), and let's say the true correlation coefficient of either with y is +1. Then any solution satisfying a + b = 1 (assuming a constant c) will have the same associated cost.

Comment: Thanks @Paul. Ca you explain your suggestion of intialising theta with values of same order of magnitude and what you meant by distribution of solution. I am a bit new in this area

Comment: Sorry for the late reply (life is hectic at the moment). You have two solutions for theta already and the magnitude of the values is somewhere in the thousands. If you initialise theta with very small values, you will always start in the same region of solution space and hence always converge on the same solutions. You should hence initialise your theta with much larger values, e.g. `theta = 1000*np.random.randn(n, 1)`. You should then repeat the process a bunch of times (with different random initialisations) to find out if the solutions that you have so far are actually that different.